# Run my own script inside Chrome's debugger console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm tired of re-typing the same commands into Chrome's developer console. Is it possible to load a script that I have saved on my local machine?

Comment: This is precisely what the upcoming Snippets support is all about:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support

Comment: check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/include-javascript-file-in-chrome-console

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're running developer tools on a file:// URL, you can do something like:

```
s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = 'file://path/to/script.js'; 
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

As a workaround you could also paste in your oft-repeated code snippet into the developer tools.

Comment: `(function() { var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'; 
document.body.appendChild(s); })();`

Comment: This now returns the error "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: Works well in Chrome 64 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

As @PaulIrish pointed out in the comments Chrome's `Snippets` are their solution to this problem.  This screenshot below shows were to find snippets within Chrome's developer tools as of this writing.  To run a snippet right click on its entry in the snippet pane, pictured on the left, and select "Run":

[image]