# Include jQuery in the JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to include jQuery in the Chrome JavaScript console for sites that do not use it? For example, on a website I would like to get the number of rows in a table. I know this is really easy with jQuery.

```
$('element').length;
```

The site does not use jQuery. Can I add it in from the command line?

Comment: For more of an automated approach you can use a userscript to include it. Seriously this would be like a 5 line userscript :P

Comment: `document.getElementById('tableID').rows.length`. If the table doesn't have an ID, use the DOM editor to give it one. You don't need jQuery for something so absurdly trivial.

Comment: There is a chrome extension to do this - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/script-injector/fddnddnolonllcgfbenaloajnbhebmob

Comment: add it to a script tag, either from cdn or locally. CDN is much simpler.

Comment: I believe most of the major browsers' Dev Tools now include jQuery (and a few other popular libraries like Underscore) by default, but am unable to find documentation of it. Pop open the console it usually Just Works (tm). ------ Also, this approach has (now) long since been built into a handy bookmarklet by several people. I have used this one successfully: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet.

Comment: Did you know that the dollar sign function has already been loaded in Chrome devtools? You can use `$` to query select elements

Answer (score 1587, accepted):

Run this in your browser's JavaScript console, then jQuery should be available...

```js
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type (or see below for non wait option)
jQuery.noConflict();
```

**NOTE:** if the site has scripts that conflict with jQuery (other libs, etc.) you could still run into problems.

#### Update:

Making the best better, creating a Bookmark makes it really convenient, let's do it, and a little feedback is great too:

1. Right click the Bookmarks Bar, and click **Add Page**
2. Name it as you like, e.g. Inject jQuery, and use the following line for URL:

> javascript:(function(e,s){e.src=s;e.onload=function(){jQuery.noConflict();console.log('jQuery injected')};document.head.appendChild(e);})(document.createElement('script'),'//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js')

Below is the formatted code:

```js
javascript: (function(e, s) {
    e.src = s;
    e.onload = function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jQuery injected');
    };
    document.head.appendChild(e);
})(document.createElement('script'), '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js')
```

Here the official jQuery CDN URL is used, feel free to use your own CDN/version.

Comment: This snippet didn't work for me. Had no time to figure it out why. Just copied http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js file content and pasted into console. Works perfect.

Comment: couldn't this be written as:

```
javascript: (function(e, s) {
  var element = document.createElement('script');
  var jqueryUrl = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';


    element.src = jqueryUrl;
    element.onload = function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jQuery injected');
    };

    document.head.appendChild(e);
})
```

?

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas, had time to figure it out, added a solution that works with bookmarks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76834783/2707890

Comment: The URL 'code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' contains jQuery v.1.11.1, which is a very old version (here's the [explanation why](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/)). You should use specific version insted.

Answer (score 281):

Run this in your console:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

It creates a new script tag, fills it with jQuery, and appends to the head.

Answer (score 125):

Copy everything from:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

And paste it into console. Works perfectly.

Comment: Works like a charm! And it doesn't add script to DOM which sometimes it's not possible due to 'Content Security Policy Directive'. I've tried accepted answer which resulted in: Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src ....

Answer (score 67):

Use the jQueryify booklet:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190502132317/http://marklets.com/jQuerify.aspx

Instead of copy pasting the code in the other answers, this'll make it a clickable bookmark.

Answer (score 40):

*Post 2020* method, using:

- [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports)
- [self executing IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
- [asynchronous
  function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
(async () => {
  await import('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')
  // Library ready
  console.log(jQuery)
})()
```

---

Without using `async`, and since `import` does return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), we have to use `.then()` :

```js
import('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')
  .then( () => {
    console.log(jQuery)
  }
)
```

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367916/2494754)

https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import

Answer (score 31):

Adding to @jondavidjohn's answer, we can also set it as a bookmark with URL as the javascript code.

**Name:** Include Jquery

**Url:**

```
javascript:var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq); setTimeout(function() {jQuery.noConflict(); console.log('jQuery loaded'); }, 1000);void(0);
```

and then add it to the toolbar of Chrome or Firefox so that instead of pasting the script again and again, we can just click on the bookmarklet.

[image: Screenshot of bookmark]

Answer (score 30):

I'm a rebel.

Solution: don't use jQuery. jQuery is a library to abstract the DOM inconcistencies across the browsers. Since you're in your own console, you don't need this kind of abstraction.

For your example:

```
$$('element').length
```

(`$$` is an alias to `document.querySelectorAll` in the console.)

For any other example: I'm sure I can find anything. Especially if you're using a modern browser (Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera).

Besides, knowing how the DOM works wouldn't hurt anyone, it would only increase your level of jQuery (yes, learning more about javascript makes you better at jQuery).

Answer (score 14):

I just made a jQuery 3.2.1 bookmarklet with error-handling (only load if not already loaded, detect version if already loaded, error message if error while loading). Tested in Chrome 27. There is no reason to use the "old" jQuery 1.9.1 on Chrome browser since [jQuery 2.0 is API-compatible with 1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/).

Just run the following in Chrome's developer console or **drag & drop it in your bookmark bar**:

```
javascript:((function(){if(typeof(jQuery)=="undefined"){window.jQuery="loading";var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js";a.onload=function(){console.log("jQuery "+jQuery.fn.jquery+" loaded successfully.")};a.onerror=function(){delete jQuery;alert("Error while loading jQuery!")};document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)}else{if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){alert("jQuery ("+jQuery.fn.jquery+") is already loaded!")}else{alert("jQuery is already loading...")}}})())
```

[Readable source-code is available here](https://fs.fnkr.net/UzyzudnA8l7d)

Answer (score 9):

The [top answer, by jondavidjohn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474386/527702) is good but I'd like to tweak it to address a couple of points:

- Various browsers issue a warning when loading a script from `http` to a page on `https`.
- Just changing `jquery.com`'s protocol to `https` results in a warning if you try it straight from the browser's URL bar: `This is probably not the site you are looking for!`
- I like to use Google's CDN when I'm using the console to experiment with Google sites such as Gmail.

My only issue is that I have to include a version number where in the console I really always want the latest.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 8):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38700405/2213784):

```
fetch('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js').then(r => r.text()).then(r => eval(r))
```

For some reason I have to execute it twice to get the new '$' (which I have to do with the other methods as well), but it works.

This is the equivalent if your browser isn't so modern:

```
fetch('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js').then(function(r){return r.text()}).then(function(r){eval(r)})
```

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy to do this manually, as the other answers explain. But there's also the [jQuerify plug-in](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc).

Comment: +1 - Thanks Ken. The word jQuerify reminded me that I created a bookmarklet to do this. I added my own answer that had the code I used. I knew I had done this before =).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18754187)

Comment: @adamb, unfortunately, along with the tendency of old links to decay, my time and motivation to improve some of these very old answers has concomitantly dissipated over the years. Thanks to the design of SO, however, you are more than welcome to improve the answer yourself — a contribution to the struggle against entropy that is always heartily appreciated.

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, Firebug embeds the `include` special command, and jquery is aliased by default:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include

So in your case, you just have to type :

```
include("jquery");
```

Florent

Answer (score 3):

this answer based on @genesis answer, at first I tried the bookmark version @jondavidjohn, and it is not working, so I change it to this (add it to your bookmark):

```
javascript:(function(){var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);console.log('jquery loaded')}());
```

words of caution, is not tested in chrome but work in firefox, and not tested in conflict environment.

Answer (score 3):

Modern browsers (tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari) [implement some helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244912/1476885) using the dollar sign `$` that are very similar to jQuery (if the website doesn't define something using `window.$`).

Those utilities are quite useful for selecting elements in the DOM and modifying them.

Docs: [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#selector), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands)

Answer (score 2):

One of the shortest ways would be just copy pasting the code below to the console.

```
var jquery = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(jquery);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this for a userscript, I wrote this: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/123588

It'll let you include jQuery, plus UI and any plugins you'd like.  I'm using it on a site that has 1.5.1 and no UI; this script gives me 1.7.1 instead, plus UI, and no conflicts in Chrome or FF.  I've not tested Opera myself, but others have told me it's worked there for them as well, so this ought to be pretty well a complete cross-browser userscript solution, if that's what you need to do this for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery frequently from the console you can easily write a userscript.
First, install Tampermonkey if you are on Chrome and Greasemonkey if you are on Firefox. Write a simple userscript with a use function like this:

```
var scripts = [];

function use(libname) {
    var src;
    if (scripts.indexOf(libname) == -1) {
        switch (libname.toLowerCase()) {
            case "jquery":
                src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
                break;
            case "angularjs":
                src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js";
                break;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Library already in use.");
        return;
    }
    if (src) {
        scripts.append(libname);
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(scr);
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid Library.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative code:

```
javascript:(function() {var url = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'; var n=document.createElement('script');n.setAttribute('language','JavaScript');n.setAttribute('src',url+'?rand='+new Date().getTime());document.body.appendChild(n);})();
```

which can be pasted either directly in Console or create a new Bookmark page (in Chrome right-click on the *Bookmark Bar*, *Add Page...*) and paste this code as URL.

To test if that worked, see below.

Before:

```
$()
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)
```

After:

```
$()
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Turnkey solution :

Put your code in `yourCode_here` function. And prevent HTML without HEAD tag.

```js
(function(head) {
  var jq = document.createElement('script');
  jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js";
  ((head && head[0]) || document.firstChild).appendChild(jq);
})(document.getElementsByTagName('head'));

function jQueryReady() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    yourCode_here(jQuery);
  } else {
    setTimeout(jQueryReady, 100);
  }
}

jQueryReady();

function yourCode_here($) {
  console.log("OK");
  $("body").html("<h1>Hello world !</h1>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bookmark solution working in Chrome as of 2023.
This makes it so that you don't need to copy paste the injection script every time.

```
javascript:(function(){var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);console.log("jQuery injected");})()
```

Set this in the  `URL` field of your Chrome bookmark.

After clicking on the bookmark you can do something like this in the console:

```
$('element').length
```

Answer (score 0):

intuitive one-liner

```
document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E’))
```

You can change the `src` address.
I referred to [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493936/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-jquery#comment12024263_9493985)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just save the jQuery content in a snippet(chrome) and run (Right click+Run or CTRL+Enter) it on which ever site you want. It's not necessarily jQuery any javascript if you want to run it on demand. (for ex: SharePoint JSOM..  just save all JSOM files as snippets and run it in the required order)

Answer (score -1):

i have built upon the accepnted solution and made it better

```
var also_unconflict = typeof $ != "undefined";

var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

if(also_unconflict){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $=jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jquery loaded, use jQuery instead of $')
    }, 500)
}else{
    console.log('jquery loaded, you can use $');
}
```

i'm using this function in google chrome console snippet