# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jgesture plugin for pinchopen and pinchclose events.
 but i am getting the following error:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

does any one knw the solution?
Thanks

Comment: [You need to link to jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Setup). Browsers don't just come with it yet. :)

Comment: Hi..i have added the link also  <script src="../jquerymobile/jgestures.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: If you're still having trouble after following @Sid's advice, you should validate the page and come back here after you fix the validation errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded jQuery (so jquery-1.7.1.min.js or something in that direction) before you loaded jgestures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link to jQuery from one of the hosted locations, e.g.:

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Or downloaded it from jquery.com and put it in your web server path and include in your HTML files.

Comment: Or, what is better, use the Google CDN (http://scriptsrc.net/) for loading jQuery with a local fallback: `<script>window.jQuery || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="path/to/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>`