# How to get access to functions written in Chrome extension from the JS dev console?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to call functions that I am writing in a Chrome extension from the JS console in Chrome, so that I can test them easily and see how their output changes as the page changes.

But it seems as the functions I write aren't available to the chrome JS console.  I don't really understand JS that well, or the chrome extension model, but I need to somehow inject the extension source into the body of the page that I am using the extension for?

Comment: These pictures show where to find the features you're looking for: [animation for Content scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197993/938089) and [picture for background page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/938089).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about functions that you defined in a `background page`, then you need to go to your extensions page, check the developer mode box, and click on `_generated_background_page.html`. That is where you will find your background page code.

If you mean functions in a `content script`, then when you are in the console, go down to where it says `<page context>` and change it to your extension. Then you will have access to the functions in the `content script`.