# How do I inspect child frame in webkit inspector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, inspector

I have a javascript application which uses a child window frame. Is there any way for me to change the focus of the webkit inspector to the child frame so that I can inspect elements on it?

Comment: Im assuming you mean an iframe?

Comment: See pic at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197993/938089

Comment: @luke I am actually using node-webkit, a project using chromium to make node.js desktop apps. I have a child window I am using for logging that I want to be able to inspect with the webkit inspector.

Comment: @Rob I have tried this approach but it appears that this is related to iFrames and not separate windows. There is no drop down option for my child window