# Jquery .each() not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autogrow

I am using the Jquery [Elastic](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/). It works fine with Firefox but fails in chrome. I have only one textarea I am using it on.

HTML:

```
<textarea id = "tarea">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
```

Binding  the textarea with the plugin function:

```
$(document).load(function() { $('#tarea').elastic() ;  }) ;
```

I opened the plugin file and found through `alert` statements where the execution stops in chrome:

```
--- code above this initializing arrays, works fine in both FF and chrome
    return this.each( function() {
                 -- Chrome does not execute anything in the callback
                // Elastic only works on textareas
                if ( this.type !== 'textarea' ) {
                 
                    return false;
                }
       .
       .
       .
                } 
   --- return ends here , chrome does not execute anything here either.
```

I have checked the JS for error with firebug and found nothing. I have a similar plugin for chrome as well and even that does not report any javascript errors.

Update :

I changed the call to the plug from being a `'load'` event to a `'ready'` event. And it works now. I can't understand why though.

Comment: can u set up a fiddle

Comment: If it's not getting anything in the callback, because there's nothing in '`this`' to '`each`', before the line `.each()`, `alert( this.length );` and check if `this` is definitely an `typeof jQuery` object, otherwise you might need to re-wrap it, `jQuery(this)`.

Comment: `this` is a DOMnode (which doesn’t have a property `type`) and thus the function returns right there once the check against `'textarea'` fails?

Comment: @ tobi It doesn't go to the callback. The check is never performed. 

@ Mackieee alert(this.length); returns 0. The typeof returns 'object'. I wrapped it with jquery as well but it did not help.

Comment: Question updated. Please check.

Comment: @tobi `this` should be a DOM node that represents an input, and **does** have a property of `type`.

Comment: From the doc for the load-event: " This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object." I suspect trying to call `$(document).load(function() {...});` just immediately executes the callback, and therefore doesn't work to delay execution until the elements exist. That would explain why switching to `.ready()` did work for you.

Comment: there is no document load, there is window load, window unload and document ready in jquery

Answer (score 0):

> Note: For Chrome, do not expect $ is always `JQuery`.

You can put `$` into console to check if it returns `ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`, if yes means $ is not defined for `JQuery`.

That's a good news that you have below ways to try:

1. **Solve the conflict of using `$`, let it be `jQuery` without any ambiguity**

Firstly, you can put this code snippet

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";  /* Include any online jquery library you need */
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

into the Console, 
then put `$.noConflict` into console, if it not returns `undefined`, but returns `ƒ (t){return e.$===w&&(e.$=Kt),t&&e.jQuery===w&&(e.jQuery=Jt),w}`, it means `$` is not defined for `JQuery` now.

Next you can continue to input your regional code, then you will find it works well now.

**Refer**: https://blog.wplauncher.com/run-jquery-in-chrome-console/

2. **Using `.js` file instead in Chrome, then debug the JavaScript file.**

**Refer:** [Chrome DevTools Snippets](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/)

3. **Besides, for some specific version of Chrome, there is a option in UI to set the `page context`** (**probably removed** this function in latest version!)

[image: img].

**Refer:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581276/6075331, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197993/6075331