# Debugging Chrome extension with access to chrome.devtools api

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am beginner in Chrome extensions development. I need to extend existing extension ([angularjs-batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang)), but I have some problems with debugging.

`manifest.json` has entries:

```
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtoolsBackground.html"
```

The question is: how to debug `devtools_page`? I added to `manifest.json` additional entry 
`"options_page": "devtoolsBackground.html"` and when I add this extension to Chrome I have possibility to run `options` page from `chrome://extensions`. 
It works because application stops at breakpoints. But unfortunatelly I have no access to `chrome.devtools` API. So it is not solution.

How can I debug this and have access to this API?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To open the developer tools for a devtools page, I usually follow the following steps:

1. Open the developer tools.
2. Undock the developer tools if not already done (via the button in the bottom-left corner).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open the developer tools of the developer tools.
4. Optional: Feel free to dock the developer tools again if you had undocked it at step 2.
5. Switch from "`<top frame>`" to `devtoolsBackground.html` (or whatever name you have chosen for your devtools). ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197993/938089))
6. Now you can use the Console tab to play with the `chrome.devtools` API.

Comment: Any suggestions if you need to debug the js in a DevTools panel that you have created?  I would like to open the code and drop a breakpoint in there.  When I try the method above all I see is the js that runs for the devtools_page, not the js for the panel itself.

Comment: @AbeMiessler The method from my answer works just fine for devtools panels (Chromium 41.0.2272.77). Did you look in the right devtools, *after* activating the panel? The panel is lazy-loaded, i.e. it is only loaded when you click on the tab.