# SidebarPanel Size in DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Surprisingly the SideBarPanel is not the full height of the container by default. I can't figure out how to make it 100% height. This is what it looks like currently.

[image]

Notice how its a little less than half the height of the sidebar container. Other panels don't have this issue. I've tried setting the html and body of the panel to 100% through CSS, and I've tried calling

`sidebar.setHeight('100%');`

both before and after `sidebar.setPage`. Instead of doing anything, it causes *nothing* to be displayed (probably because it doesn't support % height from this method). I don't know how to debug the JS or CSS of devtools extensions, so I am not sure how to figure out what is breaking. I know error's can be viewed from the Chrome Devtools Extension, but no error is thrown in this case.

---

As a bonus question, showing me how to debug devtools extensions would be nice. (Googling impossible since you just get normal debugging guides.)

Comment: I didn't read the rest of your question, but the answer to your bonus question does already exist at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875605/debugging-chrome-extension-with-access-to-chrome-devtools-api/19875684#19875684.

Comment: @RobW Ah, thank you! It works, I'll see if this helps me fix the main problem.

Comment: I've found that '100vh' works, but actually makes the pane TALLER than the visible area - it seems it's 100% relative to the overall sidebar 'viewport' height.

Comment: That's the closest i've come. Put it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this when googling, this looks like it's currently fixed in Chrome canary: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438126