# Typing `chrome.devtools` in the console causes a hard crash of Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've made an empty chrome extension to poke around `chrome` DOM object in the dev tools inspector, but every time I submit the command `chrome.devtools` in the console I get a hard crash of Chrome. Does anybody know how I can get around this? It appears I can access the other parameters in the `chrome` object. When I try to add `chrome.devtools` to the Watch, it will be added but when I expand the object Chrome crashes.

[image]

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test Extension",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.1",

    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body { min-width: 200px; min-height: 120px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**devtools.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="devtools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the `.js` files are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome crashing due to access to `chrome.devtools` is a known bug: https://crbug.com/356133.

I guess that you're not deliberately trying to crash Chrome, but want to inspect the `chrome.devtools` API via the console. If that is indeed your goal, open the devtools for a devtools page as explained at [Debugging Chrome extension with access to chrome.devtools api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875605/debugging-chrome-extension-with-access-to-chrome-devtools-api/19875684#19875684).