# Google Chrome Developer Tools Issue with Jquery in the Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When I try to execute below JQuery code in Google Chrome's developer tools

```
$("#u_16_0").val("AJ College, Sivakasi")
```

am getting below error:

> Uncaught Error: <[EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it
>   is not present on the page.","#u_16_0"]]]>(…)h @ LGuPoDEwQGD.js:36i @
>   LGuPoDEwQGD.js:36(anonymous function) @ VM580:1

Could somebody please help me to resolve this issue? I've verified that the element is present in the page. I mean if I just type `$("#u_16_0")` in the console, the element is printed.

Please see the below link to screenshot containing version information of my Google Chrome.

[[image: Google Chrome Version]

**UPDATE - 1**

I managed to accomplish this with the below plain javascript code

```
document.getElementById("u_16_0").value="University of Cambridge"
```

**UPDATE - 2**

> Amin's answer based on jQuery also worked. Hence, accepted it as answer and awarded bounty.

Comment: What kind of element is `#u_16_0` in this context?

Comment: Can you post the html of the element?

Comment: It is <input type="text"/>

Comment: Can you post the actual markup, you can right click on the element on th page and click `inspect element`, it will show the mark up the element. Then right click on the mark up and then copy and then click `copy outer html`. Can you post the same here?

Comment: @Programmer You can check the animation version below in my answer to fix this.

Comment: @IvanChaer - I confirmed that there's no <iframe> tag in the source code of the page.

Comment: Are you on Facebook where $ is not jQuery. `$("contentCol")`

Comment: @epascarello - Yes, you're right. In Facebook, it appears that $ is not jQuery. I accomplished this with plain javascript and updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of jQuery `$` sign conflict with other libraries like some facebook js libraries.
you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`:

```
jQuery("#u_16_0").val("AJ College, Sivakasi");
```

Comment: I tried this as well. Getting error: `VM882:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: @Programmer make sure that jquery library included properly.
for example:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Amin - Unfortunately, I do not have access to the source code of this web application.

Comment: @Programmer you should copy content of jquery librarie file and paste into console then press enter.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

Answer (score 7):

*Note*: Do not expect **$** is always JQuery.

> The Chrome console does not appear to have access to the content script's execution context.

Wrong, it does. You need to look at the correct place:

Instead of `<page context>` below in the animation, you have to select `chrome-extension://<your extension id>`

You can click "top" below in your version of chrome.

[image]

[image: Animation of how-to get access to the execution environment of the Chromne extension]

The previous screencast shows that the Console tab of the Chrome developer tools has two dropdown boxes at the bottom, which can be used to change the execution environment for the developer tools' console.
The left side can be used to change the frame context (top frame, so iframe, ...), and the right side can be used to change the script context (page, content script, ...).

Reference: [Why will jQuery not load in Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194699/why-will-jquery-not-load-in-facebook)

Comment: I do not see a page context option in my console. Is it not available in my version?

Comment: If you go to the console, you can see "top" which you have to click

Comment: If you go to the console, you can see "top" which you have to click and select `chrome-extension://<your extension id>`

Comment: I have updated the screenshot for your chrome version. Please look at my answer above.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that typing `$("u_16_0")` in console prints the element.

Comment: You can select a correct `chrome-extension://<your extension id>` in the dropdown and execute `$("u_o_0")` in the console. If you are not sure which one to select, you can try selecting one by one and executing it in the console.

Comment: Also, noticed, you seem to be trying this `$("u_16_0")` now. Instead, you can try with `#` as `$("#u_16_0")`

Comment: @ Aruna Plain javascript code worked perfectly. I've updated my post. Let the answer be auto selected and bounty awarded accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is when you assume that `$` is always jQuery and it is not. Simple way to see if it is to `console.log($)` and see what it returns.

jQuery usually returns

```
function (selector,context){return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context)}
```

or

```
function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

Now anyone can define `$` to be anything. On Facebook it appears to be an alias for `document.getElementById()` and has some checks in it

```
function i(j){return h(j);}
```

running `$("contentCol")` will return a DOM element.

And if `$` is not defined, in Chrome Dev tools, it is an alias for `document.querySelector`

```
$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

so in the end, do not expect `$` to be jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286152/203371) it looks as though your call to:

```
$("#u_16_0")
```

is not actually calling jQuery.

Try changing the page context

[image]

Comment: I do not see a page context option in my console. Is it not available in my version?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that typing `$("u_o_0")` in console prints the element.