# Chrome Extension not loading/ code environment not selectable in Inspector/ Dev tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension to highlight the Facebook Notifications using jQuery.
I can get it to load, when Facebook loads first time, but after a while it stops working.
In manifest I have tried persistent set to true and false, no difference.
I have tried using background.js.

I have been fiddling with chrome.tabs.onActivated and .onHighlighted and can get an alert to show up, but my code or the jQuery $ isn't seen.

In dev tools, my extension isn't listed in the environments I can choose to use here [image: Chrome Dev Tools environment chooser]

My Code:
manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Facebook Your notification highlight",
    "version": "0.3.2",
    "description": "Highlights notifications with 'your' in the notification!",
 "background": {
      "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": "icon48.png"
    },
 "icons": {
  "48": "icon48.png",
  "128": "icon128.png" },
 "permissions": [ "tabs", "webNavigation", "https://www.facebook.com/" , "https://facebook.com/", "http://www.facebook.com/"],
 "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

New manifest.js

```js
{
    "name": "Facebook Your notification highlight",
    "version": "0.3.3",
    "description": "Highlights notifications with 'your' in the notification!", 
 "background": {
      "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","background.js"]
  },
 
  "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": "icon48.png"
    },
 "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*.facebook.com/"],
          "js": ["jquery.min.js","inject.js"]
        }
  ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
  "jquery.min.js",
  "inject.js"
  ],
 "icons": {
  "48": "icon48.png",
  "128": "icon128.png" },
 "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs", "webNavigation", "https://www.facebook.com/" , "https://facebook.com/", "http://www.facebook.com/"],
 "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

new inject.js

```
//add listeners when injected


$(document).ready(function() {
    AddFbListeners();
});



function AddFbListeners() {
    $('div#js_11.uiScrollableAreaWrap').scroll( function() {
        HighlightFb(); 
    });

    $('#fbNotificationsJewel').click ( function () {
        setTimeout( HighlightFb(), 250);
    });
}

function HighlightFb() {
    //alert("highlight");
    //highlight you
     $("._33c:contains('you')").find('*').css("background-color", "#CCCC00"); //greeny yellow
    //highlight your
     $("._33c:contains('your')").find('*').css("background-color", "66CC00"); //darker yellow
    //highlight reacted or liked
     $("._33c:contains('liked')").find('*').css("background-color", "#b2b300");  //mustard
     $("._33c:contains('reacted')").find('*').css("background-color", "#b2b300"); //mustard
     //mentioned
     $("._33c:contains('mentioned')").find('*').css("background-color", "#62b300"); //green
    }
```

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect your background page by going to `chrome://extensions` and clicking the ***background page*** or ***background page (inactive)*** link for your extension. (Chrome runs your background scripts on a minimal implicitly generated background page `background.html`.)

Your general logic is flawed though, **extension pages** (and scripts - typically a background page, options page, pop-up etc.) **run in a separate environment and have no access to the DOM of regular pages**. You need a [**content script**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for your `HighlightFb()` and `AddFbListeners()` to let them access the DOM of a regular (in your case Facebook) page. (BTW, content scripts will be listed in the environment selector in Chrome DevTools of a regular page.)

The differences between the context of extension pages vs. content scripts vs. regular pages have been addressed many times on StackOverflow, but it might be best to read up on extension architecture in general first:

[Extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) (Chrome)

[Anatomy of a web extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) (Firefox, but the architecture is essentially identical)

Comment: Thanks @Petr, I have tried using a content script before, but I will try again and feedback :)

Comment: I did come to this conclusion myself actually I think, and switched to content scripts

I have added my updated maniffest.json to the question.

Comment: I removed the line "run_at": "document_end" and it seems to be working now.... from the "new manifest.json" script as above...

Comment: Actually Petr it has disappeared again :( the content scripts are not there in the inspector... I wonder if it has something to do with what this post is talking about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools?rq=1
Maybe @rsanchez will have some ideas?

Comment: I don't think that your issues have anything to do with Facebook blocking the console (that seems to be a 5 years old thing). Please update the code in your question to your current version so I can investigate. Your current `new` code is chaotic at a quick glance. BTW, are you fiddling with `chrome.tabs.onActivated` and `.onHighlighted` for learning purposes? Because you don't need them to highlight an element on a page.

Comment: Yep @Petr, that is right - just playing/ trying to look for ways to get the script to inject...

Comment: removed background.js and updated manifest.json new to reflect current code.

Comment: btw. I just loaded the extension into Firefox, as is. And so far, it works every time.. .go figure.

Comment: I dont have much time to play with it right now, but I believe that your `scroll` event listener never fires, because Facebook has its own scroll event listener attached to `window` which cancels the event before it gets a chance to bubble to your listener. I would suggest a different approach - perhaps looking for inserted notification elements to highlight using a `MutationObserver`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you are using JQuery. with JQuery reference to injected HTML doesn't work and FaceBook does a lot of that. How to go around this is to write your event listeners in a different way.
instead of:

```js
$("#item").click(function(){
// do something here
})
```

Use this rather:

```js
$(document).on("click","#item",function(){
//do something here
})
```

Comment: Thanks Doc. The issue is more getting the scripts to load at all...? I tried changing this, but not seeing a change to the actual script loading / being available as an environment to work in in dev tools?