# Chrome extension to modify `Node.prototype`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a content script that adds members to `Node.prototype`. These aren't visible from the Developer Console because of the "isolated world" concept at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.

How can I create a Chrome Extension whose modifications to `Node` are visible when using the Developer Tools Console on pages for which the extension was applied?

So the following steps would validate the solution:

1. (Create the extension with various content_scripts or any other strategies
   to work around isolated worlds)
2. Open Chrome and browse to a page for which the extension is applicable
3. Open Developer Tools Console
4. Enter the command `Node.newMember;`
5. See some POC value appear, such as a string `"Hello World"` which was set by the extension in (1)

Some background info: This is for an extension that I want to create as a timesaver to make various properties permanently accessible through `$0` when selecting various nodes in the DOM.

Comment: If you only need it in the dev console you can switch to content script context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197993/1507998
If you really need to inject your code in the page context take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/1507998

Comment: @rsanchez's comment with link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194699/why-will-jquery-not-load-in-facebook/15197993#15197993 is the answer

Comment: @rsanchez You should make that into an answer.