# .focus() not working in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

This code should create little numbered tags next to each anchor, button, and input element. It then sets up click events on those tags. I have removed the code for the buttons and anchor tags, since it works and is unrelated.

With inputs, however, what should happen is that the cursor should be placed into the input element, achieved using the `.focus()` method.

But when I run this in the console against a logged-in gmail.com, it does nothing. The commented `alert()` statement will return `[Object HTMLSpanElement]`, whatever that means. If I uncomment the `document.getElementById` line to focus on the search bar *directly*, it works. Why doesn't  it work using `this`?

I'm using gmail just for a testing example, but this behavior is on all pages, the bug is always there. You can include jQuery to test this in the console using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console).

```
var n = 1;
$('a,button,input').each(function(){
                        id = n;
                   //creates numbered tags next to 'a', 'button' and 'input' elements
                        var a = $(this).offset();
                        $('body').append('<span class="numTag" id="' + id + '" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + id + '</span>');
                        $('#'+id).css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});
                        switch( this.tagName)
                        {
                        case 'A':
                            break;
                        case 'BUTTON':
                            break;
                        case 'INPUT':
                            $('#'+id).click(function(){
                                //alert(this);
                                this.focus();
                                //document.getElementById('gbqfq').focus();
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        n++;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: this is not the object you are expecting inside the click function. use the 'var self = this;' outside the function, then inside the function use self.focus();

Comment: You never declared `n`

Comment: Why would you focus an input after clicking it? shouldn't clicking it already cause it to gain focus?

Comment: @Izzey that was a transcription typo, edited.

Comment: Aha, i see. you're clicking the span. Therefore, `this` is the span, and spans can't gain focus.

Comment: Ah....................That seems so obvious now.

Comment: You need to store `this` in a variable before the switch

Comment: use each(function(i){   i then is your index or "n" or "id" and you dont need to count it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing access to `this` inside the click event. Store a reference to it so that you can access it later.

```
var self = this;
$('#'+id).click(function(){
    //alert(self);
    self.focus();
    //document.getElementById('gbqfq').focus();
});
```