# jQuery.post() from the browser console

Tags: jquery, post, console

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console). There it is said that jQuery can be run on any site by adding the script tag in the console which links to jQuery.

My question: Can this be a security issue where anyone can run `$.post()` and post random data to the server? Anyone can view a javascript file on a website and obtain the `url` of a jQuery post statement and also the data which can be posted. This can also bypass validations on the client side.

Comment: Anone can also write their own web page that contains a form with `action="yourURL"`.

Comment: They can also run `curl` from the command line or a PHP script, and connect to your server script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not just a jQuery issue - any javascript command can be run via the console.

Yes it is a potential security issue, but one you should be aware of. Client side validation should be used as a courtesy to the user for a better user experience. You *must* also have server-side validation on every request to ensure that the data sent is valid, no matter what the source was.