# Scrape/Retrieve Data from Data Grid - DOM to CSV console output

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, gwt, web-scraping

I want to scrape the 
Cell Widgets -> Data Grid on this page:
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid

Ideally I am looking for csv style string output like
(first line and last line example)

```
;Corey;Jenkins;63;Coworkers;438 Techwood St;
.... (many rows here)
;Yvonne;Morris;55;Family; 483 Third Pkwy;
```

(I am working with Firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');

jq.onload = function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();

    // Our stuff...
    (function ($) {
        $('table').find('tr')
            .each(function(j, rowitem) {
                var line = ''
                $(rowitem).find('div').each(function(i, item) {
                    var o = $(item).find('option[selected]');
                    if (o.length > 0) {
                        line += $(o).text();
                    } else {
                        line += $(item).text();
                    }
                    line += ';';
                });
                console.log(line);
            });
    })(jQuery);
}

// Load jQuery as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/7474386/22972
jq.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you are trying to do this to build a site scraper on gwt website. In the above example each of the row has a identifying attribute across each of the grid rows represented by TR tags. For the first TR tag you will have **`__gwt_row="0" __gwt_subrow="0"`**.

You will also have cell attributes of type **`__gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-29"`**

The above two attributes on row and cell should allow you to easily do a XPATH lookup and iteration to scrape the page and output into a csv file.