# How to download files in bulk from browser console using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, download, console, automation

I have no experience with web programming, so my question would be a very simple one. I want to download a lot of files by filling out forms in a web page. The web page's extension is `.aspx`, and I am interested in only one field and a button. By fooling around with the console in my browser, I figured out that executing:

```
document.getElementById('TxtRegNo').value = 'blahblah`;
```

will fill the concerned field. Also doing a

```
__doPostBack("ImageButton1","Click");
```

will download the `.pdf` file curresponding to `blahblah`. The actual value which needs to be entered is a sequence like PAG-1200 to PAG-1900. I tried using a for loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 21618; i < 21621; i++) 
{
document.getElementById('TxtRegNo').value = 'B14-' + i;
__doPostBack("ImageButton1","Click");
}
```

but it doesnot work as expected. only the last document gets downloaded, and I get this in the console:

[image]

Thought this error does not come whe nI run in FireFox's console, I can still run only one file. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I tried adding a refresh after  the `doPostBack` but the page gets refreshed before the download starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Inject jQuery to the page via the console, as explained here: [Include jQuery in the JavaScript Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console)
2. In your for loop clone the form, set the values as you wish and submit the form `jQuery('form').clone().find('#TxtRegNo').val('blah').parent('form').submit();`

If the page contains more than one form, you should specify it. `'form'` works like css selectors here. This will find all forms on the page. Just use `'#elementId'` or `'.elementsClassName'` to be more concrete, if necessary.

Maybe you also need to change the name of the form (to be able to submit the forms simulatiously). I didn't try it, this is just a guess.

If you want to split the code to several lines you can also do this:

```
var myFormClone = jQuery('form').clone();
myFormClone.find('#TxtRegNo').val('blah');
myFormClone.attr('name', 'uniquename_' + iterationVariableOfForLoop);
myFormClone.submit();
```

If the submit failes, try:

```
myFormClone.get(0).submit();
```

Good luck!

Comment: When I type `var jq = document.createElement('script');`, it says `undefined`

Comment: I think this is normal, because this line of code is not returning anything. It is assigning the created script to the variable. Do a `jQuery()` console first, and you get undefined. Then execute all lines of the other answer and try again :)

Comment: Am I supposed to execute all the lines in the other answer as it is?

Comment: Yes! But the last one (`jQuery.noConflict()`) needs to be a little bit delayed. Because jQuery needs to be loaded, first. But then the whole magic of jQuery is available :) And if the page contains no other JavaScript framework using `$`, the conflict mode is unnecessary.

Comment: This is what I get, no download, http://picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_screenshot_from_2015-07-09_223521.png