# How to get the unique words on a large webpage (at least a sample of unique words)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, bigdata

I am trying to process the visible text of very large pages and, as an example, the whole of [Orwell's "1984" on this page](http://msxnet.org/orwell/1984), but it seems my Chrome console is crashing when I try the following operation.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var allWords = $(document.body).children(":visible").text().split(' ');
var uniqueWords = allWords.filter(function(elem, i, array){ return array.indexOf(elem) === i });
```

The above makes my Chrome tab become unresponsive at the last operation (I stop getting output for new commands I enter for at least a minute). Note: the first part of the snippet just [attaches JQuery to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console).

How would you try to process large strings like this much, much faster? Do you think I should randomly sample from `allWords` and only apply the filter function to this smaller string.

Comment: In your orwell's example, I got response in time with no delay in my chrome tab. Do you process even bigger data?

Comment: The Orwell example is the largest one I have tried and I do get a delay. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why chrome tab is hanging after last line executes is complexity of your algorithm. Instead of calling `.indexOf` on each word you can just add each word to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
var uniqueWords = new Set();
allWords.forEach(function (word) { 
    uniqueWords.add(word) 
});
```

If you need ES5 version of the same code, you can use helper object as data storage. Object keys are unique by nature, so you can fill empty object with words as keys and whatever you want with values and then extract words with `Object.keys` method

```
var uniqueWordsHash = {};
allWords.reduce(function (hash, word) {
    hash[word] = null;
    return hash;
}, uniqueWordsHash);

var uniqueWordsArray = Object.keys(uniqueWordsHash);
```

Comment: That's excellent. I should add that I needed to do something like `Array.from(uniqueWords)` to actually get back an array which is what I was after.