# How to fetch data from ajax.inc.php page, using node modules?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js

I use node.js and I want to get this `http://myanimelist.net/includes/ajax.inc.php?t=64&id=1` page and fetch some data I need. I wasn't able to make it with cheerio, because I've never encounter with such a kind of pages before. I'll be glad if someone tell me how to parse such pages and which node module use for it since I wasn't able to figure out it with google, however I understand that it should be easy and I'm just asking silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is simple extracted output from html output via my code.

```
{
   "description": "In the year 2071, humanity has colonized several of the planets and moons of the solar system leaving the now uninhabitable surface of planet Earth behind. The Inter Solar System Police attempts to ke...",
   "genres": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Drama, Sci-Fi, Space",
   "status": "Finished Airing",
   "type": "TV",
   "episodes": "26",
   "score": "8.83",
   "ranked": "#22",
   "popularity": "#31",
   "members": "419,197"
}
```

Below is code which extracts the info from page and saves it in an object (key:value) pair (i.e., like the above);

```
var $body = $('body');

$('div').children().empty();
var description = $('div').text().trim();
var keys = $('body span').text().split(':');
keys.splice(-1, 1);
$body.children().empty();
var values = $body.text().trim().split('\n');

var result = {
    description: description
};

for(var j = 0; j<keys.length; j++) {
    result[(keys[j].toLowerCase().trim())] = (values[j].trim());
}

console.log('result', result);
```

To test the above code you need to open http://myanimelist.net/includes/ajax.inc.php?t=64&id=1 and paste the above script in Dev Tools inspector -> console. when you run the code it will throw result because jquery isn't found the page so manually add the jquery into your scripts via this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474394/5228251

You need to use this ^code using `cheerio` to parse the page.

## UPDATED

Use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) npm modules;

Installing modules;

```
$ npm install request --save
$ npm install cheerio --save
```

Using this script;

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request');

function scrapePage(callback) {
    var result = null;
    var url = 'http://myanimelist.net/includes/ajax.inc.php?t=64&id=1';

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Page URL.

            var $ = cheerio.load('<body>' + body + '</body>');
            var $body = $('body');

            $('body div').children().empty();
            var description = $('body div').text().trim();
            var keys = $('body span').text().split(':');
            keys.splice(-1, 1);
            $body.children().empty();
            var values = $body.text().trim().split('\n');

            result = {
                description: description
            };

            for(var j = 0; j<keys.length; j++) {
                result[(keys[j].toLowerCase().trim())] = (values[j].trim());
            }
        }

        callback(result);
    });
}
```

usage:

```
scrapePage(function(result) {
    console.log('result', result);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It works in browser however I still cannot understand how to use additional script with cheerio. It seems there isn't opportunity to create element and then run script within the loaded page with cheerio. Probably, I just should use jquery or phantom module instead request and cheerio which I use now. And I have a lot of pages to visit, so I'm a bit worried about time which will be spent to load my pages with information and  library for each of them.

Comment: don't worry. you still can with cheerio. basically cheerio is just like a jquery for node js. you don't need to include jquery either.

Comment: I have updated the answer. please find after *UPDATED* heading.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, but I'm getting empty string as a result in my terminal. I have 0.20.0 version of `cheerio` and 2.72.0 `version` of request. Maybe I should change them?

Comment: uncomment the line `console.log(body)` and see what is response html check if its valid or not.

Comment: ok i got this.. here is a fix. just replace this line `var $ = cheerio.load(body);` with `var $ = cheerio.load('<body>' + body + '</body>');` I have tested it on my side. It works. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I  was about to write there is no body tag in response html, now it works!

Comment: Have fun -  enjoy. Cheers.