# Parse html of current page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, parsing, tampermonkey

I want to make a script that will parse the html of the current page, filtering out certain div classes and for now to write their contents to a file or remove everything else but them on the page.

I guess the best way would be to run a Tampermonkey script on that page. I looked on http://userscripts-mirror.org/ but didn't find a script like this.

Is there a javascript html parser that can run on chrome?

Something that could work like this maybe?

```
 var divClasses = parseCurrentPage("div class x");
 // then do something on divClasses and then show only them
```

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is explicitly off topic.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse the html of the current page"? You should be able to use `.querySelectorAll()` or `.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Try pulling the full page source and using regex maybe?

Comment: @Brydenr I hoped to automate the part where I pull the html locally, I also hoped there's already a tool that can filter div classes.

Comment: _"I also hoped there's already a tool that can filter div classes."_ Does `document.getElementsByClassName()` not return expected result?

Comment: It may be too heavy, but looking at web browser automation like selenium may be what you want, though I hesitate to endorse a (free) product on stack overflow.

Comment: Have you tried using .html() to pull out a copy of the whole thing, then .remove() or .removeChild() to get rid of the divs?

Comment: @SilentLupin I'm afraid I'm new to js and even newer to jquery so I'll have to google those..

Comment: @guest271314 looks like `document.getElementsByClassName()` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery can do all of this and more. I would recommend reading up on it https://learn.jquery.com/

Once you have included jquery a simple grab all "div" elements selector would be something like this:
`var divClasses = $('div');`
If you want to only grab certain div elements you can easily do this using selectors, either by adding class, id, and/or parent/hierarchy level restrictions to the selector - read more here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Then after you did your something you want to do on the div elements you can again use jquery to only show them using jquery's 'append' function.

Simple call the ['append'](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function with the div element you want to append on the parent html element
`$('selector-to-grap-div\'s-parent-html').append(myDiv);`
if you need to grab the parent of one of the div elements then you can use jquery's ['parent'](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function

Comment: Nice, can you also work on the contents of `var divClasses` with jquery? something like a `removeif("div has a certain word")`

Comment: most definitely! if you are referring to having a certain word in the text of the div then you can simply use jquery's 'text' function - api.jquery.com/text then use a javascript str.indexOf to see if the word you are looking for is contained in the div's text. If it is then you can remove it using jquery's remove api.jquery.com/remove var myDivsText = myDiv.text(); if (myDivsText.indexOf("wordLookingFor") >= 0) { myDiv.remove(); }

Comment: When I try to run `var divClasses = $('div');` in chrome's console, it either returns `undefined` or throws `Tried to get element with id of "%s" but it is not present on the page.` I did try to include it in several ways like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console maybe I'll open another question...

Answer (score 1):

> filtering out certain div classes

You can use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> ```
> var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names); // or:
> var elements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName(names);
> ```
>
> - *elements* is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements.
> - *names* is a string representing the list of class names to match; class names are separated by whitespace
> - getElementsByClassName can be called on any element, not only on the document. The element on which it is called will be used as the root
>     of the search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make it easy with jQuery... just get the content of `<body>` and do your queries with jquery.

Comment: Can you remove all the divs but certain ones in jquery?

Comment: @kuhaku you can use $("div") to get all them... and then with forEach go and check and remove some