# How can I use jQuery in the Firefox Scratchpad?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How can I go about using jQuery in the Firefox Scratchpad? 
I have Firefox v54.0.1.

I googled it and found some articles mentioning how the Firefox Scratchpad had jQuery built-in but those articles were written back when the Scratchpad was first released.

http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/jquery-and-javascript-development-using-firefox-scratchpad

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/11/reintroducing-the-firefox-developer-tools-part-2-the-scratchpad-and-the-style-editor/

I originally just tried the jQuery code and when it wasn't working I threw in the CDN for it.. I was desperate..

Any suggestion is appreciated! 
Thanks!

[image: Firefox Scratchpad Screenshot]

EDIT: (Added Dave's suggestion)

[image: Firefox Scratchpad Screenshot 2]

Comment: You can inject `jQuery` in `browser console` instead of scratchpad itself, here is how: [Include jQuery in the JavaScript Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7474354/3367974)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to inject a script element by adding this code at the beginning of the scratchpad. Additionally you need to wait for it to load, you you'll need to run your code in a callback

```
let jq = document.createElement("script");
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js";
jq.onload = function() {
  //your code here
};
document.body.appendChild(jq);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @dave! Although now I get a new error. I have edited the question with the problem. Could you help me out again please and thanks!

Comment: @RickyDam check the updated answer. Also there was a typo in the original answer that would have caused a problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic way to load any script (or maybe just AMD-enabled script) using [**`almond.js`**](https://github.com/requirejs/almond) (you can replace it with [**`require.js`**](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs) too if you want).

Place this script in the beginning of the scratchpad snippet. This snippet loads the **`almond.js`** script loader.

```
var _ = function (run) {
  var script = document.createElement("script") 
  // replace this url to load any other script loaders...
  script.src = 'https://gitcdn.link/repo/requirejs/almond/master/almond.js';
  // then run the code once require is available
  script.onload = function () {
    run(requirejs)
  }
  script.onerror = function () {
    // uncaught!
    throw new Error('error loading almond!')
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

Now, you can wrap your scratchpad code like this

```
_(function(require){
    // here you may configure requirejs to load external scripts
    // see: https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config
    // For e.g. to load jQuery you can do something like this
    require.config({
      path: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'
      }
    })

    // then trigger require js
    require(['jquery'], function($){
      // your code follows here...!
    })
})
```