# import or require any library in browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, ecmascript-6, browser-console

While debugging application most of the time I feel like it would hve easier if I could include any library into browser console and try some of the function from that libraty.

Now in modern `javascript/es6/es6/typescript` world is there any thing short and quick available to to import a script instantly to the brower so that it can be used to directly

#### Example

While debugging, if I want Observable I should be able to do something like this

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';  //typescript way
const Observable= require('rxjs/Observable'); // require way
```

But these are not working.

#### already explored [dynamic `<script>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console)

I already explore old way to dynamically using the `<script>` tag like below but its dificult for large number of libs and also not elegant

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type (or see below for non wait option)
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: is there anything! I face the same situation alway! hope there is a easy way

Answer (score 14):

Some browsers ([including Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets)) can use snippets in console, either as built-in features or extensions.

One-liner script to do this is

```
document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(
    document.createElement('script'),
    { src: '...' }
));
```

Considering that most websites already have jQuery loaded (even if they don't, this can be handled by browser extensions, such as Chrome [jQuery Injector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/ekkjohcjbjcjjifokpingdbdlfekjcgi?hl=en)) it can be shortened to:

```
$.getScript('...');
```

Any piece of code that should be always available in console can also be exposed as global function with user scripts (Tampermonkey in Chrome, etc), with some limitations imposed by user script security.

This will **probably** will be possible with [dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), which is currently stage 3 proposal and isn't implemented in browsers.

---

A suitable solution that works for most major libraries the one may be curious to quickly experiment with is **to navigate to official library website** and open the console. Due to the fact that the websites often provide live examples, relevant variables are exposed to global scope. Known examples are `$` for [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), `angular` for [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), `ng` for [Angular](https://angular.io/), `Rx` for [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/), `moment` for [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)...

Comment: its kind of same as creating  a script tag and appending external script to it. I am looking something one liner to read the script from a link and execute it and export me the module like node or typescript file

Comment: There's no one-liner you're asking for. The solutions to the problem are listed. $.getScript nails it.