# Hide an HTML element annotated with ng-show from the browser source code on inspect element

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML element annotated with ng-show which I hide/show the element based on a boolean value that's toggled between true/false on a sibling  element on ng-click(). When I inspect the element in the browser, I always see the  annotated with ng-show, even if it's hidden.

Here is my div with ng-show:

```
<div ng-show="!showWhatsNewSection" </div>
      ...
```

And here is my  element which toggles showing / hiding the whats new section.

```
<span ng-click="showWhatsNewSection = !showWhatsNewSection"> </span>
```

Is there any way to hide the whatsNewSection from the browser source code on inspect element when that section is hidden (i.e. when showWhatsNewSection is false?

Comment: If you add an ID to it, I think you could try hiding it using Chrome's built-in console. Something like `$('#SomeId').hide();` You might need to follow this if you want to use jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474386/2720343

Comment: ngIf instead of ngShow? You'd still see the comments where the element is missing form, but the actual element will be gone.

Comment: As @kendavidson mentioned, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. That will remove element from DOM.

Comment: Thanks! `ng-if` is what I was looking for