# How can I test jQuery code in the browser console?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to test if my jQuery code is sound. So I thought I just enter the code in the browser console. I use Mozilla Firefox.

I want to test if I can select ids and that stuff.

But when I enter:

```
$("#testId")
```

I get the following error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: private names aren't valid in this context*

Are the elements that I want to access private? What does that mean and why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console

Comment: jQuery is available on that site already

Comment: Which site? How have you included the jquery source? Did you try the linked answer?

Answer (score 3):

just type

```
console.log($("#testId"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you dont have access to jQuery in console (window/document).

You can add the jQuery script to DOM directly from console by creating and appending the script to body:

```
let s = document.createElement('script')
s.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js')
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s)
```

And now eg get the jQuery version:

```
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)
```

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps to test & practice JQuery in your console:
first, use the browser debugger tool to inspect any element in your browser, view the source code, e.g like classNames and id'

Next, now use the jQuery syntax to select it example $(".className") or $("#ids"),

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<div id="testId">hi user1664377</div>
```

then

```
console.log($("#testId").text()); // you will see "hi user1664377" in console
```

Comment: so I cannot do that in the browser console? Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can be tried.

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src=`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```