JavaScript Doesn't Always Load
I am trying to build a website, the JavaScript code that is supposed to add the sticky navigation menu when the header is not visible doesn't work properly. It was working without any problems when I hosted the website locally; but, when I hosted the website on a server it doesn't always work.
There are two JavaScript files for different stuff, one works flawlessly. The one that is causing problems is using JQuery, I surmise that maybe it is JQuery that is causing problems.
After reloading the site many times, it starts to work as intended. Also, this error shows up in console when this happens;
script.js:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:34:5
(anonymous) @   script.js:34

Here are the codes that are causing problems.
The JavaScript file;
if (window.location.href.replaceAll(window.location.origin, '').replaceAll('/', '').length === 0 || window.location.href.includes("index.html")) {
    $(window).scroll
        (
            $(window).onload = function () {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
                    $(window).innerWidth
                        (
                            function () {

                                if ($(window).innerWidth() < 460) {
                                    $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
                                    $('nav div').removeClass('visible-title');
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
                                    $('nav div').addClass('visible-title');
                                }

                            }
                        );


                }
                else {

                    $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
                    $('nav div').removeClass('visible-title');
                }
            }
        );
} else {
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 460) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('nav div').removeClass('visible-title');

    } else {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('nav div').addClass('visible-title');
    }
}

The HTML file;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

    <head>
        <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
        <script async
            src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXX"></script>
        <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'XXXXXX');
    </script>

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" async src="/script.js"></script>

        <script id="MathJax-script" async
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
        <title>Arşiv</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../RezonansLogo.png">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="site-title"><a
                        style="color:white; text-decoration: none"
                        href="../index.html"
                        target="_self">Rezonans Kulübü</a></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/sayfalar/yazilar.html">Yazılar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sayfalar/ekip.html">Ekip</a></li>
                    <ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <section class="content">
                    <article>
                        <h1>Örnek.</h1>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </body>

        </html>

I tried loading the script inside the body tag but it didn't helped at all. I tried downloading JQuery, it also didn't solved the problem. I tried to remove the async tag, that somewhat worsened the issue. I also tried to incIude a JQuery fallback. I am out of ideas at this point.
Post Scriptum: I suppose these are very inefficient and absurd, sorry for that. Thank you in advance.

Do you see any error in the console or network monitor regarding loading jQuery?

Yes, I saw this error;
script.js:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at script.js:34:5
(anonymous) @   script.js:34

No, I mean errors regarding the loading of jQuery, not regarding the usage.

Oh, no there isn't any error other than this.

When you check the request for jQuery in the network monitor, do you see status 200 and the source code for jQuery in the response?

I think async is the problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#async: "For classic scripts, if the async attribute is present, then the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available." That means, if /script.js is fetched before https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js, it will be parsed before $ is set.

Yes even when the problem happens I see status 200 and the source code.

I would use ES modules instead. That allows async fetching and solves problems with dependencies.

I just tried to remove the async attribute. Now, JavaScript never work, and there is no error in console.

Yes, that's because now DOM rendering is blocked until the scripts are fetched and evaluated. The scripts don't find the DOM elements. You can use async with defer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer That should guarantee the correct order. I'm not sure about the last sentence "If the attribute is specified with the async attribute, the element will act as if only the async attribute is specified." I understand it as adding defer shouldn't change anything.

Okay, I will try to use ES modules. Thank you.

I think, this should help or answer the second question Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element if I put the script element near the top of the page?

I tried to use async and defer but the problem still persisted. But, while trying to add async and defer I accidentally added only defer and saw that defer solved the problem. Thank you for everything.

defer "essentially" moves your script tag to the bottom, just before </body> - you could also do that and remove defer/async.   Your issue was with async running as soon as it loads (as detailed by @jabaa).  Removing async then runs your code before the DOM loaded - the other option would be to put your code in that's in script.js inside a doc.ready.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63860970/2494754
