# C-style include in Firebug or Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, console, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include javascript file in chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/include-javascript-file-in-chrome-console)

Is there any way to include javascript file in the console from arbitrary location in my local  filesystem? e.g. something like the C style #include "/path/to/script.js"

Comment: I saw that one, but I'm thinking of a one liner where I can just open new browser tab and type import "/path/to/the/js" in the console straight away. Could be very useful if you test lots of javascript modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug doesn't have this yet, but [it will probably be added in the next version](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5878) (out in December or so).