# How to load javascript from url in js console(for example chrome Ctrl + Shift+ J)

Tags: javascript

I have webserver and I want to host there .js which I want load with simple/not so simple javascript code from chrome js console to modify webs etc... I don't have experience with javascript much and I wasn't able to google solution for this so I would like to know how to do what is in title, thanks for help :)

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do it so idk...

Comment: This may be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/include-javascript-file-in-chrome-console