# How to include External Script using console?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know ,
How to include External JavaScript into current page using developer console.

I am having static plain html/js i want to test it with several js libraries as well as css in it. without adding in `.html` file or i am from remote machine.

so how do achieve it using Developer console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/include-javascript-file-in-chrome-console)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to inject your script into `HTML` DOM

```
inject = document.createElement('script');
inject.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(inject);
```