# How to add jQuery in browser for testing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How to add **jQuery** in browser for testing.

1. Using javascript
2. IN browser where jQuery not enabled by default

**Like using script tag???**

Comment: [Here](https://jquery.com/download/) is a list with different options.

Comment: [This might be helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/how-to-include-javascript-file-or-library-in-chrome-console).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet to inject jQuery using developer console

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```