# How to import javascript file in browser console?

Tags: javascript, developer-tools, google-developers-console

I have a .js file and I want to use it on some webpage (I am not developing this script for website, I just want to use my script on company's webpage). Look, it works like an extension very well, but I am looking for a way to launch my .js in browser console. Is it even possible to do this? I tried (intuitively) to import my file through Developer Tools – Sources – Filesystem and use it, but it's not working. Debugger is cursing, and the script is not working. Or it should be working and webpage has some kind of 'anti-cheat'?
P.S.: No, I can't just copy-paste the code into the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include JavaScript file or library in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/how-to-include-javascript-file-or-library-in-chrome-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tamper monkey or any other user script injector