# How to export GitHub issues into a Word (docx) document?

Tags: json, docx, github-issues

The long and stupid way is listed below, but hoping that someone has a way quicker and nicer solution. (Didn't have time to come up with a proper Node or Deno solution, so I spent better part of the day on this abomination.<sup>[quote](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/)</sup>)

1. **"Install" [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) and [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)**

   ```
   nix-shell -p gh pandoc
   ```
2. Export GitHub issues in JSON

   The minimum GitHub issue properties required in the JavaScript snippet below:

   ```
   gh issue list --json title,body,url,number
   ```

   Use this to see all available issue properties:

   ```
   gh issue list --json
   ```

   One can filter the issues too if needed:

   ```
   gh issue list --state open --label "for_stakeholders" --json title,body,url,number
   ```
3. Copy the terminal output from the previous step to the JavaScript console in Chrome Dev Tools:

   ```
   > issues = ...copy here...
   ```
4. On the same JavaScript console, copy and execute the following lines too:

   ```js
   // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/how-to-include-javascript-file-or-library-in-chrome-console
   async function loadScript(url) {
     let response = await fetch(url);
     let script = await response.text();
     eval(script);
   }

   // Doesn't seem to work on the console without a top-level `await`
   await loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/2.1.0/showdown.min.js');

   // Needed to convert Markdown to HTML; see https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown
   const mdConverter = new showdown.Converter();

   function issuesJSONToHTML(issues) {

       let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
       h1.textContent = "Lynx issues";

       let newBody = document.createElement('body');

       // Convert `issues` array JSON and put into `newBody`
       issues.
           // `gh` outputs issues in reverse chronological order
           reverse().
           map( (iss) => {
               let section = document.createElement('section');

               let title = document.createElement('h2');
                   title.innerHTML = `<a href="${iss.url}">#${iss.number} ${iss.title}</a>`;
               let body = document.createElement('p');
                   body.innerHTML = mdConverter.makeHtml(iss.body);

               section.appendChild(title);
               section.appendChild(body);

               return section;
           }).
           forEach( (iss) => { newBody.appendChild(iss); })

       // Replace the site where the console is open
       // (this is mostly for instant testing)
       document.head.innerHTML = '<meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><title>Lynx issues</title>';
       document.body.innerHTML = newBody.outerHTML;

       return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
   }
   ```
5. Copy the HTML document to the system clipboard from the JavaScript console

   ```js
   copy(issuesJSONToHTML(issues))
   ```
6. Paste it into a text file (e.g., `issues.html`)
7. Convert the saved HTML file to a Word document on the terminal

   ```
   pandoc issues.html -o issues.docx
   ```