# Chrome Developer Tools: What is Snippets Support?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

In the "Sources" tab of Chrome dev tools, there is a Snippets sub-tab:

[image: The image shows a screenshot of a web browser's developer tools interface, specifically the 'Sources' tab. The tab is divided into several sections: Page, Workspace, Overrides, Content scripts, and Snippets. The focus is on the 'Snippets' section, which is highlighted with a red arrow pointing to it. There is a message below the tabs explaining that you can 'Save the JavaScript code you run often to run it again anytime,' and a link to 'Learn more' about this feature.]

What can I use this for?

Comment: There is now hugely complete docs on snippets: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets Enjoy

Comment: @PaulIrish The link's page doesn't contain snippets part anymore.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In short, snippets are a multi-line console, an iterative JS development workflow, and a persistent store for common debugging helpers.

**[developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets)**

> Some of the use-cases Snippets can help with are:
>
> - **Bookmarklets** - all of your bookmarklets could be stored as snippets, especially those you may wish to edit.
> - **Utilities** - debugging helpers for interacting with the current page can be stored and debugged. A community-curated list of such utilities is available.
> - **Debugging** - Snippets offer a multi-line console with syntax-highlighting and persistance, making it convenience for debugging code that is more than a one-liner.
> - **Monkey-patching code** - code you wish to patch at runtime can be done through Snippets, although many times you can just live-edit code in the Sources tab.

[image: snippets screenshot]

Lastly, I've personally been collecting a few common snippets that you may include in your arsenal: [github.com/paulirish/devtools-addons/wiki/Snippets](https://github.com/paulirish/devtools-addons/wiki/Snippets)

---

To run snippets quickly, now you can do this. Ctrl-Shift-P for the "command palette", then backspace, and use a ! prefix, then type whichever snippet name you want to run.

[image]

Comment: What would be the fastest way to execute a snippet? I could to Ctrl+Shift+I (open DevTools), Ctrl+P (fuzzy search), start typing snippet name, ENTER (open snippet), Ctrl+ENTER (execute snippet). I hope I'm missing something and there's a faster way. A "snippets toolbar" in the browser would be nice.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas that's the fastest way I know. What snippet do you use so often you want it on speed dial?

Comment: I need this one to watch YouTube: `javascript:(function(){location.href=location.href.replace('youtube.com/watch','youtube.com/watch_popup')}())`. (I'm Flash-less and YouTube only loads HTML5 videos in its "watch_popup" page for me. See here: https://twitter.com/simevidas/status/368054720327204864). Also [jsgif](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/) for viewing animated GIFs. I got hooked on those two, so I keep my bookmarks toolbar open permanently.

Comment: I wonder if Paul Irish has ever answered a question, and *NOT* been marked as the right answer....

Comment: @ŠimeVidas the "tampermonkey" extension is a similar tool I've recently discovered that can run js code based on url.

Comment: I've noticed that Snippets haven't been included in Canary for quite some time now. Does anyone know why?

Comment: How can a snippet be run from a bookmarklet?  (Is it even possible to do so? Perhaps there is or could be a Chrome browser extension that can help expose them to bookmarklet javascript? Snippets have marketed as an [alternative to bookmarklets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en), but they aren't quite an alternative for me if they can't be as easily executed from a web page as a bookmarklet.)

Comment: Unless or until snippets can be accessed from things like a bookmarklet, folks can use local js files instead of snippets as is described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611796/is-there-any-way-to-load-a-local-js-file-dynamically/10612311#10612311

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Unfortunately, I could not find any faster way. I would have hoped for finding them in the IntelliSense-like popup while coding in the console.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas to run snippets quickly, now you can do this. Ctrl-Shift-P for the "command palette", then backspace, and use a `!` prefix, then type whichever snippet name you want to run.

Comment: @PaulIrish Or Ctrl-P, so that the field is empty and you don't have to delete the `>`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 12):

I asked Paul Irish if he knew anything about it, he wasn't sure either but says it's not completely implemented yet and pointed me at the bug tracker, I found the head [ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75094) and looking at some of the code the diffs have a lot of `FIXME: To be implemented.` comments.

Comment: It's almost done. It allows effectively a multiline console but with saveable/nameable input.

Comment: I figured as much, I'm really excited about this feature.

Comment: Better answer by vidar a few answers below

Comment: The UI is currently crude. On Windows you can only save snippets using Ctrl+S (just make sure that the focus is on the right window). There doesn't seem to be a shortcut to run the snippet though.

Comment: Chrome stores your snippets in localstorage so I don't think you can easily edit them externally. Your best bet is to edit externally and copy into devtools.

Answer (score 9):

Right click to create a new one.

[image: Chrome DevTools Snippets — New]

Answer (score 5):

Chrome Developer Tools snippets support allows to create/edit/save and execute javascript code snippets.

Comment: This feature is now working on the most recent builds of chrome but UI is not very nice yet. Snippets could be manipulated from the navigator context menu.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to activate that experiment myself (there's no `Developer Tools experiments` in my `chrome:flags`, but from Safari, I found [this](http://www.seifi.org/css/whats-new-in-safari-31-web-inspector-and-sinppet-editor.html) explanation:

In short, it "is a little utility that allows you to enter blocks of HTML and CSS and have it rendered on the fly".

From the blog post, it seems it is buggy in Safari, so maybe Chrome has not implemented it yet.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools snippets support is a completely different feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the list of useful snippets here http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/

one of the useful snippet is 'jquerify.js' - Using this you can include jQuery in to any page if it is not yet included.