# Why I can't develop single html page with linked css or js files?

Tags: google-chrome

What is wrong with Chrome? I want to develop just a single html page. Without any server. Just one page. I know that I need web-server for using that page. But I need to just create a short simple html page with linked js and css files. And I can't do this, because chrome is too smart and I get the same error from chrome:
Not allowed to load local resource

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>ACAB</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./data_statistic.js"></script>
    ....
```

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours, a simple google search on the error message gives you a few links on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611796/is-there-any-way-to-load-a-local-js-file-dynamically

Comment: Just remove the `./` or `file://` from any declared JS and CSS files.

Comment: thanx emartel, I will use Firefox.