# Execute a jquery function in chrome's console on a loaded web page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, web, console

I want to write a custom jquery function on a file, and then open any website in chrome , click on inspect element, go to console, and there i want to execute my jquery function.
 
How should i do to call the function from the file instead of writing it directly in the console ? 

(assume that the loaded web page is already supporting jquery)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10612311/1133144) solution may help you since you're using chrome (I didn't test it myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bookmarklet of it! Since you can use `javascript:` in URLs, you can create run-anywhere snippets of code you can call simply by clicking on the bookmark. My favorite pattern would be `javascript: (function() { ... })();` Stick the bookmark in your toolbar for easy access.

Nettuts has an excellent how-to on [creating a basic bookmarklet](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/).

Comment: i have another question, is there a way to write to a local file from a jquery function ? i want to write the result of my bookmarklet function to a local file , have you any idea ? thanks again

Comment: There is no "pure" JS way to save to the local filesystem. However, there are a few mixed Java/jQuery plugins available, or HTML5's local storage capabilities. This [SO question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery) cover pretty much to whole range of options.

Answer (score 0):

if you could host your file somewhere (a local iis or apache might do) then you can add the file to a websites `head` using something like this in the console

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>';
```

this example adds the `jquery` file to the head.