# Running a JavaScript file in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, terminal, console

I would like to run a local javascript file in chrome console but do not want to copy and paste the code. I know there is a command I can run from terminal to open the file in a new chrome window/tab but cannot recall it nor find example of it on-line.

What command can I call from the terminal to open a .js file in a new chrome tab where I can then run it in console?

Comment: Have you tried to make a js snippet in chrome? You can find the snippets in Chrome Dev Tools -> Sources -> Snippets -> New -> Run.

Comment: No, I have not. I'm not entirely positive what that is nor is that what I am trying to achieve, I believe.

Comment: The main thing that you can do with the snippet is to run a random script in a page (whatever page). Give it a try, it may be what you are seeking.

Comment: I looked into it, and it would be useful, so I appreciate that piece. However, the question still remains as to how to open a .js file from command line and have it run in chrome console/access to it's contents (variables/functions/etc.) in console.

Comment: Nice thing the snippet, I didn't know. thanks Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly that. To run JS with having access to the console, you can either copy its source to the console or to the address/location bar (`javascript:(js code here)`).

The simplest way I can think of to achieve your goal is to wrap the JS in an HTML file and call chrome with `chrome -u file:///path/to/file.html`. Include the JS in a `<script>` tag also with the file:/// protocol in the `src` attribute to point to the local file or using a relative path.

When chrome opens, you should have access to functions/variables defined in your code as global variables.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but was consciously avoiding using an HTML doc I am almost entirely positive you can call a javascript file from the command line in such a way that it is opened and run in console.

Comment: I really don't think there's a way out of the box. However, you might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611796/is-there-any-way-to-load-a-local-js-file-dynamically?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I'm afraid you're correct and I must be misremembering my experience of doing so... I will ultimately be wrapping this in an HTML doc and going about it in this way. This is currently the most correct answer. Thanks!