# ChromeDevTools: Backward search in history

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a `reverse-search-history` in ChromeDevTools?

The bash shell has a this great feature:

> reverse-search-history (C-r)
>
> Search backward starting at the current line and moving ‘up’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html

Would be very cool to have this while working with JS code in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

There has been another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672502/how-to-filter-chromes-devtool-console-history) regarding this topic and there have even been some [chromium devs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171386) working on it. From what I've read, the feature got dropped because it would conflict with the existing autocomplete functionality of the console. There is a hack in the above mentioned SO post by Bob, but there is no official feature.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I starred the feature request. Maybe this helps to get it implemented: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171386

Comment: How is this still not implemented... thanks for the definitive answer...