# Can I access JavaScript snippets using chrome.devtools API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to make a Chrome Developer Tools Extensions that needs access to newly added snippets  in sources pane.

Does chrome.devtools API have any way to access snippets?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can do it through [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow API()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html)

**You can track**

[a) Content of all Snippets available](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-getResources)

[b) When ever a new Snippet is added and its content](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceAdded)

[c) When ever a Snippet is Updated with new content\modified.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceContentCommitted)

How ever for enabling the debugging etc you have to [enable experimental developer flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support).

You can take following code as a reference and you can extend it as per your requirement.

**manifest.json**

You have to add

> "devtools_page":"devtools.html",

code to your manifest.json file

***Sample manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Snippets Demo",
"description":"This demonstrates How to get content from Snippets API",
"devtools_page":"devtools.html",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"2"
}
```

**devtools.html**

Add `devtools.js` to avoid [inline scripting](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)

***Sample devtools.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**devtools.js**

*Add related code for*

**a)** [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-getResources)

**b)** [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceAdded.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceAdded)

**c)** [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted.addListener()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceContentCommitted)

***Sample devtools.js***

```
//Fetching all available resources and filtering using name of script snippet added 
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources(function (resources){

    // This function returns array of resources available in the current window

    for(i=0;i<resources.length;i++){

        // Matching with current snippet URL

        if(resources[i].url == "Script snippet #1"){
            resources[i].getContent(function (content,encoding){

                alert("encoding is " + encoding);
                alert("content is  "+content);
            });
        }
    }

});

//This can be used for identifying when ever a new resource is added

chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceAdded.addListener(function (resource){
    alert("resources added" + resource.url);
    alert("resources content added " + resource.content);
});

//This can be used to detect when ever a resource code is changed/updated

chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted.addListener(function(resource,content){
    alert("Resource Changed");
    alert("New Content  " + content);
    alert("New Resource  Object is " + resource);
});
```

After putting all the 3 codes together you get

*Output 1)*

[image]

*Output 2)*

[image]

*Output 3)*

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Relying on `url` of resources is not safe. User can change name of snippet on creation. I need to be sure that the resource is a snippet. 

It's not really impossible to `console.log` in the script. Context of that script is not usual window. It runs in it's own context (`devtools.html`). To access devtools for that script you can reach out to `chrome://inspect` to see that page.

While this is very helpful, I still can't access just snippets. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mohsen: Thanks for appreciating, Apart from filter `resource.type=='script'` there are no specific filters for snippets or Experimental API()'s available till date :(

Comment: resource.content returns always "undefined" is this code not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this but the accepted answer is quite old and, as of Jan 2016 you cannot access snippets via `localStorage`.

also see:

https://github.com/bahmutov/code-snippets/issues/23
[Which file does Snippets of Chrome Dev Tool saved at?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025718/which-file-does-snippets-of-chrome-dev-tool-saved-at/25871853#25871853)