# Which file does Snippets of Chrome Dev Tool saved at?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

As I know , personal data always be saved at profile path which can be find at chrome://version.

I added many snippets in my Chrome Dev Tool, and want to backup them .

But I cann't find a file that snippets data saved in under this path.

Does anyone knows ? Plz tell me . Thanks very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of Chrome 47 (or so), snippets are no longer available via localStorage. Also, natchiketa's answer is dependent on localStorage and also doesn't work any longer.

Below is the current technique:

#### getting snippets

```
InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences(_ => console.log(JSON.parse(_.scriptSnippets)))
```

#### setting snippets

```
InspectorFrontendHost.setPreference("scriptSnippets", JSON.stringify(yourSnippets))
```

This technique was extracted from a [github thread](https://github.com/bahmutov/code-snippets/issues/23) discussing this change.

Comment: The github thread explains this, but you need a devtools-on-devtools setup to get this to work. (Launch devtools *undocked*, then press Cmd+Opt+I or Ctrl+Shift+I) from with devtools focused to open a new devtools that inspects the original one.

Comment: how do i restore the snippets from chromes profile folder? i had to reset windows and im only left with the profile folder

Comment: Newbie question: I executed this and it seemed to work - outputting an array of Objects, one for each snippet. How do I save this into .js files on my harddisk?

Comment: @flow2k I'll leave that mostly to you, but the [download] attribute is key: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: RoccoB's technique didn't just point to them but actually opened up all of the snippets that went missing when things got reset

Answer (score 9):

### Working solution on latest chromium (124):

In `ubuntu`, `chromium` snippets are saved inside the Preferences `.json` file.

Possible locations:

- `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`
- `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Preferences` (snap)

To find the exact location of `Preferences` you can check the property `Profile Path` in the `chrome://version/` page and then append `/Preferences` to it.

The snippets are saved as a serialized json under the .json path:

```
.devtools.preferences.scriptSnippets
```

The value needs to be parsed as json, then you get an array of `{name,content}` pairs which correspond to the snippets.

**Note: I am using `jq-1.6` for the commands below**

**To backup** all snippets into **one json file:**

```bash
jq .devtools.preferences.scriptSnippets ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences \
| jq '. | fromjson' > /tmp/backup.json
```

To **backup all snippets** into **separate .js files** (one per-snippet)

```bash
# Tested with jq-1.6
# The script converts json entries into lines of format 
# `filename[TAB]content-in-base64` and then 
# for each line creates the corresponding file 
# with the content decoded
# encoding/decoding helps in passing to xargs

# Better be in a safe directory!!
mkdir /tmp/snippets-backup
cd /tmp/snippets-backup

jq .devtools.preferences.scriptSnippets ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences \
| jq '. | fromjson | .[]| [ .name, @base64 "\(.content)" ] | @tsv' -r \
| xargs -I{} /bin/bash -c 'file=$(echo "{}"|cut -f1); fileContent=$(echo "{}"|cut -f2); echo "$fileContent" | base64 -d > "${file}.js"'
```

#### About jq

[jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) is a great command-line tool to query and process JSON files.

Comment: You should mention at least what `jq` is and where to get it since it's a 3rd party tool. Also, my `Preferences` file doesn't contain any occurrence of the string `snippets` at all (I'm using Chrome 76.0).

Answer (score 3):

> **EDIT (Jan 2016)** *WARNING*: I can only assume from recent downvotes that this doesn't work anymore. I'll update when I have a chance.

## TL;DR

- Snippets are stored as sqlite files.
- You can extract them as an array of `[{id: n, name: 'foo.js', content: "The script"}]`
- Instructions for OS X are below

On OS X, assuming you have a sqlite command line client installed (I had one already and I don't recall installing one explicitly), you'll find it this way:

# If you don't know what Chrome Profiles are, you probably use Profile 1, so:
    cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 1/Local\ Storage

In this directory you should have a file called `chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage`, if so, you should be able to do:

```bash
sqlite3 chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
```

...and you should be in the sqlite shell, which starts out like this:

```
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

You can do `.tables` to see the tables in this file:

```bash
sqlite> .tables
ItemTable
```

And then you can do this to see the column names in that table:

```sql
PRAGMA table_info(ItemTable);
```

Since localStorage is just a key/value store, this table is pretty simple:

```
0|key|TEXT|0||0
1|value|BLOB|1||0
```

What would be much more illuminating would be to see the key names:

```
select key from ItemTable;
```

And you should see something like this:

```bash
fileSystemMapping
showAdvancedHeapSnapshotProperties
lastDockState
resourcesLargeRows
networkResourceTypeFilters
pauseOnCaughtException
showInheritedComputedStyleProperties
elementsPanelSplitViewState
filterBar-networkPanel-toggled
networkLogColumnsVisibility
networkPanelSplitViewState
sourcesPanelDebuggerSidebarSplitViewState
pauseOnExceptionEnabled
watchExpressions
breakpoints
consoleHistory
domBreakpoints
Inspector.drawerSplitViewState
InspectorView.splitViewState
WebInspector.Drawer.lastSelectedView
currentDockState
editorInDrawerSplitViewState
experiments
inspectorVersion
lastActivePanel
sourcesPanelSplitViewState
sourcesPanelNavigatorSplitViewState
scriptSnippets_lastIdentifier
previouslyViewedFiles
revision-history
revision-history|Script snippet #1|20267.2|1410876616909
scriptSnippets
```

The snippets are in `scriptsSnippets`. I had no snippets when I started to do this, and so I didn't see this key. Upon creating my first snippet, the key appeared. So next I did:

```sql
select * from ItemTable where key = 'scriptSnippets';
```

Et voila!

```bash
scriptSnippets|[{"id":"1","name":"SnipFoo.js","content":"/**\n * @license\n * Lo-Dash 2.4.1 (Custom Build) <http://lodash.com/>\n * Build: `lodash modern -o ./dist/lodash.js`\n * Copyright 2012-2013 The Dojo Foundation <http://dojofoundation.org/>\n * Based on Underscore.js 1.5.2 <http://underscorejs.org/LICENSE>\n * Copyright 2009-2013 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors\n * Available under MIT license <http://lodash.com/license>\n */\n;(function() {\n\n  /** Used as a safe reference for `undefined` in pre ES5 environments */\n  var undefined;\n\n  /** Used to pool arrays and objects used internally */\n  var arrayPool = [],\n      objectPool = [];\n\n  /** Used to generate unique IDs */\n  var idCounter = 0;\n\n  /** Used to prefix keys to avoid issues with `__proto__` and properties on `Object.prototype` */\n  var keyPrefix = +new Date + '';\n\n  /** Used as the size when optimizations are enabled for large arrays */\n  var largeArraySize = 75;\n\n  /** Used as the max size of the `arrayPool` and `objectPool` */\n  var maxPoolSize = 40;\n\n  /** Used to detect and test whitespace */\n  var whitespace = (\n    // whitespace\n    ' \\t\\x0B\\f\\xA0\\ufeff' +\n\n    // line terminators\n    '\\n\\r\\u2028\\u2029' +\n\n    // unicode category \"Zs\" space separators\n    '\\u1680\\u180e\\u2000\\u2001\\u2002\\u2003\\u2004\\u2005\\u2006\\u2007\\
```

...and so on. Note that you'll see more than one version of your snippet. I just pasted `lodash.js` in that new snippet I mentioned above, and already I have it twice.

So, how to actually get the script out of this? Well, once you get the `value` field, that's just a JSON array, where you have a snippet `id`, `name` and `content`. So create a SQL script to pass to `sqlite3`, from the command line, like this:

```bash
echo "select value from ItemTable where key = 'scriptSnippets';" > showSnippets.txt
```

And then feed that script like this:

```bash
sqlite3 chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage < showSnippets.txt
```

It's slightly prettier to look at if you do this:

```bash
sqlite3 chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage < showSnippets.txt | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac

```sh
/Users/yourUserName/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences
```

Chrome save your snippets in Preferences.

Comment: Found there as kind of JSON values

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:This answer is **Out of date**, snippets are no longer saved in localstorage.

Please see **[paulirish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35002464/89484)**.

For older versions of chrome this might work.
its stored here C:\Users\Webdev\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage.
but I don't think you can view it from the file path,

you can view it by doing the following.
open up the devtools and then head to chrome://inspect, under the "OTHER" heading you should see the devtools panels url you just opened, the url starts with chrome-devtools://dev.
inspect it by clicking the inspect link.
a new devtools window should open, under the resources tab, go to localstorage there is a 
key called scriptSnippets, that's where its saved. just copy and paste it or use the  console panel to modify the output beforehand.

Hope this helps

Comment: Both answers no longer work. I just posted the working answer below.