# Cannot open File as Chrome Snippet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-snippets

I am looking for a javascript testing tool, like LinqPad for C#.  Chrome has snippets, which let you edit and test javascript, and that looks close.  However I cannot Open an existing file.  Ctrl+P should do it, but that just brings up this help-like dialog.

I would like to be able to edit and save these scripts.  Any idea how to do so?  Google's help is, as usual, not so helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about an html page? Javascript in browser is meant to be ran from a document. Or are you testing code that should get executed in an other environment? Then a browser is not the best place to test it... 
And for saving your snippet right-click + save-as will do, while ctrl+P is meant to open a File that is loaded from the Document (and not as a Snippet, just in the Source visualizer)

Comment: I am looking for a playground to test and run javascript.  It looks like Chrome Snippets is supposed to fill this need.  It's not really about HTML at all.  But if I cannot load and save my files, that does not help too much.

Comment: @DanielWilliams We are building something like this right now, but won't be ready for alpha testers for another month or so. Would this interest you? https://twitter.com/_MattWay/status/1070965320393707520

Comment: You can save your snippets as files (right click your snippet's name in the left panel then save as), and yes it is about HTML since in a browser javascript is dependent of the DOM. Now, there are many js playground websites if you don't mind testing in a browser env, and there might also be for nodejs if you aim this environment. ([repl.it](https://repl.it/languages) does support nodejs too)

Comment: @MattWay - yes this does look  like what I'm seeking.  Kind of like jsfiddle, but working locally.