# chrome-devtools snippets import/export 2016

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-snippets

Today I wanted to export my snippets from chrome.

I found Information from 2013:
https://github.com/bgrins/devtools-snippets/issues/28#issuecomment-27455522

I opened the DevTools 
-> to sperate Window 
-> Inspect the Devtools Itself

Then in Console:

```
->localStorage.scriptSnippets
undefined
->var stringifiedSnippets = localStorage.getItem('scriptSnippets');
undefined
->stringifiedSnippets
null
```

I tested Chrome 48 (windows), Chromium 45(ubuntu) and a Friends Chrome  on his Macbook.
How can I access my Snippets.

Has the API changed? Or am I making a mistake here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the internals have changed. Your code should change to the following:

```
InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences(function(prefs) {
    console.log(prefs.scriptSnippets);
});
```

**Note:** This script shall be run in second depth Dev Tools window! Make sure that the developer tools are undocked into a new window. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (<kbd>Command+Option+i</kbd>) to open DevTools of DevTools. In that second DevTools window, run the script above.

Comment: in G.Chrome v75 i got Uncaught ReferenceError: InspectorFrontendHost is not defined

Comment: didn't work anymore

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов This script shall be run in second depth Dev Tools window! See edited Note!

Answer (score 2):

For those who arrive here and find the accepted answer is no longer working, here is a way to access your snippets as of May 2022 Chrome 101.

1. Type `chrome://version/` on a free tab in your Chrome browser.
2. Check the "`Profile Path:`" which should be something like  `/home/your_user/.config/google-chrome/Default` for Ubuntu based OSs.
3. Find the `Preferences` file under that path and open it in a text editor. It's a big and messy JSON file. If you are making a new install at a different machine with a fresh Chrome installation then you may just copy this whole `Preferences` file under the same location in the new machine and i think your Chrome installation should have all the snippets from the original. Otherwise...
4. Search for (Ctrl+f) `"scriptSnippets"` property including the quotes.
5. I believe the snippets are in the order they are created. So not alphabetical like you see them in the snippets list.
6. My list ends with `"scriptSnippets_lastIdentifier":"142"` property which means I must have created 142 snippets so far, some removed some remaining.
7. Copy everything starting from "`scriptSnippets":"[...` up to `...}]"` excluding `"scriptSnippets_lastIdentifier":"142"` or search for the snippet of your interest by it's name and copy only that portion.

Comment: Lovely answer, as it opens the doorway to automation for sharing snippets within a team.

Comment: @Holf Yeah. Perhaps you don't even need to set up a local webserver and use Chrome DevTools itself for that purpose. [How to Use Chrome as a Local Web Server](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-chrome-local-server-mohammad-althayabeh?trk=related_artice_How%20to%20use%20Chrome%20as%20a%20Local%20Web%20Server_article-card_title)

Comment: And you can use the script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418932/1555615) to export them as separate .js files or as a single json file.

Answer (score 0):

```
InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences(function(prefs) {
    console.log(prefs.scriptSnippets);
});
```

This code works perfectly in chrome version 51.0.2704.103

Comment: I'm sorry.
I can use InspectorFrontendHost class  opening another inspector following the way explained by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome)
this topic is very nice for me thanks!