# Where are Chrome DevTools Snippets stored in Chrome 90?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Where are Chrome DevTools Snippets stored in Chrome 90?

I know I can normally retrieve them by following the instructions here:

[Which file does Snippets of Chrome Dev Tool saved at?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025718/which-file-does-snippets-of-chrome-dev-tool-saved-at)

But I accidentally restored my DevTools settings and now all my snippets are gone :(
Only on one profile though  :)

If I knew the location I could just add it to a git repo, then just commit regularly and I wouldn't have to worry about this happening again

Answer (score 1):

From reading other answers on the linked question.

Linux

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
```

Mac

```
/Users/yourUserName/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences
```

Windows

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

Comment: On Linux it's also worth checking `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`. (verified in Chrome 103).