# Running code snippets from Google Chrome console command line, using (experimental) code snippets feature?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

Reference:

[Using the new code snippets feature in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support)

I am using the code snippets in google chrome, so say I have a snippet file.
check_consistency.js

Is there an api or a global object through which we can run the snippet directly from the command line, something like:

```
  window.runSnippet('check_consistency.js')
```

or maybe call methods defined in the snippet directly.

Comment: Damn, I was really hoping for an answer to this.  Would be pretty handy to have a way to set console-scoped functions through snippets.

Comment: Raised a feature request on Devtools to add this. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358949

Comment: @VivekKodira sadly that ticket was closed as not being a priority.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Workflow Tip 1

I also want to see this functionality added. Meanwhile, perhaps try opening the `Sources` where (as you know) you can select a snippet and right click it to run it. You may or may not know that **you can tap `Esc` on this page in order to show the console at the same time** as your snippets:

[image]

### Workflow Tip 2

The [snippets documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets) also mentions

> The ability to quickly locate a specific file can be essential to a developer's workflow. The DevTools allow you to search across all script, stylesheet and snippet files using the following shortcuts:
>
> `Ctrl + O (Windows, Linux)`
>      `Cmd + O (Mac OSX)`
>
> which will work regardless of the panel you are currently in.

...and...

> A keyboard shortcut is also available for easily executing a snippet - just select your snippet then use Ctrl/Cmd + Enter to run it. This replicates the behavior of the Run (>) button - currently in the Sources console, but which will be moving into the debugger control in the near future.

### What this means is that while in the console you can press `Ctrl/Cmd+O` to quickly select your snippet, and then press `Cmd/Control+Enter` to run it.

Comment: I was looking for a chrome API so that the mouse is not involved. This new update solves the purpose.

Comment: You can also type "!" after cmd-O - this will pull up your list of snippets.

Answer (score 13):

I have a work around for when I'm running snippets a bunch of times on a site. I wrap my snippet code in a function and assign it to a global variable.

e.g.,

```
window.mySnippet = function (value) {
  console.log(value.toUpperCase());
};
```

When I run this snippet I can now run

```
mySnippet('hello world');  
-> "HELLO WORLD"
```

You still have to run the snippet once to load it into memory, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I'm using Ctrl/Cmd+O, then typing "!" to show a list of snippets. Select with cursor and Enter. Would still like to get to that point quicker, though (like Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P for commands)