# Sending email through AJAX calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, html-email, calculated-columns

I'm trying to send an automatic email receipt for items that have been created on a sharepoint list.

Conditions

1. I cannot use workflows - they are disabled
2. I cannot use webparts - they are disabled
3. I cannot use sharepoint designer etc etc etc - they are all disabled
4. The function needs to be OOTB

The only option I have is using javascript in calculated columns. I am aware of the use of the HTML:mailto tag - but this opens Microsoft outlook, and is not automatic.

Came across this link:

http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/07/03/sending-email-with-sharepoint-and-jquery.aspx

So, here is the calculated column attempt:

```
="<button onclick=""{function SendEMail(from, to, body, subject){"
&"var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;"
&"var urlTemplate = siteurl + '/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail';"
&"$.ajax({"
&"contentType: 'application/json',"
&"url: urlTemplate,"
&" type: 'POST',"
&"data: JSON.stringify({"
&"'properties': {"
&"'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },"
&"'From': from,"
&"'To': { 'results': [to] },"
&"'Body': body,"
&"'Subject': subject"
&"}}),"
&"headers: {"
&"'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',"
&"'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',"
&"'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()"
&"},success: function (data) {"
&"alert('Eposten ble sendt');"
&"},error: function (err) {"
&" alert(err.responseText);"
&" debugger;}});}"
&"SendEMail('user@whatever.com','user@whatever.com','Test1','Test2');}"">"&"Send</button>"
```

When running the code, the Console shows the following error: **'$' is undefined**

Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: If $ is undefined, the jquery has not been loaded...

Comment: So how do I get the script to load the jquery?

Comment: are you including jquery link in your script?

Comment: jquery link? The code I entered was just a straight translation of what was on that website. What has been missed?

Answer (score 0):

You keep raising the bar, Steve!

You're really making it difficult for yourself this way

I suggest the next learning steps first:

- [Learn all about Chrome Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support)
  this will help you develop/execute code directly on the View page without the need for stuffing it in a Calculated Column or any script **in** SharePoint
- Learn jQuery (by using Snippets)
  check out [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) it will inject jQuery where it is not available
- [optional] Learn [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net)
  this will help in immediatly executing your scripts on a SharePoint page (without the need for including the script **in** SharePoint
- Learn JSOM Ajax calls and REST Ajax calls (REST is halfbaked implemented in 2010)
  again; do them in Snippets first

When that all works you're halfway done and you can wrap it all in the Calculated Column (*again, this is all undocumented hacking away at Microsoft technology, if they decide to make changes in an Update you're cooked... e.g they disabled the use of the SCRIPT tag in summer 2013; that's why you now have to use the blank IMG onload trick*

Note: I have updated my [CalcMaster BookMarklet on GitHub](https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster). Once you have your Snippet working you can paste it in an existing Calculated Column Formula and wrap it in **IMG onload** and **&".."** notation with **one click**

If you get that sending email working let us know; I have never done it... I stay away from projects where SharePoint Designer can not be used.

Once you have mastered all the above you will have learned so much Front-End development I suggest you go look for another job.